# How to rearrange "sort order" column after changing the rows' sort order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, t-sql

I have a table with many lines and a column call "order" which goes from 1 to XX depends on how many line i have in my table.

The thing is, if i want to move the line with the "order" 1 to the position 3, i need the other "order" from other line to rearange themselves.

For example, if i move the "order" 1 with a "3", all the number after will have to increase of 1 and the second will have to be "order" 1 now.

I hope that i was clear.

Thanks for your help !

**EDIT / SAMPLE DATA**

```
Name   |  Order
Line 1 |  1
Line 2 |  2
Line 3 |  3
Line 4 |  4
```

If i update the order of "Line 1" with 4 instead of 1, i want the other to have their order update !

```
Name   |  Order
Line 2 |  1
Line 3 |  2
Line 4 |  3
Line 1 |  4
```

Same thing if i update the order of "line 4" with a 1 !

```
Name   |  Order
Line 4 |  1
Line 1 |  2
Line 2 |  3
Line 3 |  4
```

Same thing if i update the order of "line 3" with a 2 for example !

```
Name   |  Order
Line 1 |  1
Line 3 |  2
Line 2 |  3
Line 4 |  4
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: It's not clear, because I don't know what you mean by "moving" a line.  Records in a SQL table are, for all intents and purposes, _unordered_.  Can you include some sample data which explains your question?

Comment: It sounds odd, but have you considered using a float or other *decimal* supporting type for this `order` column? It clearly can still define an order, but you can compute a new order value (`(preceding row + succeeding row)/2`) without having to renumber other rows. (You can optionally renumber all rows on a periodic basis to bring them all back to `int` values if you feel that's necessary)

Comment: The lazy, slow, simple way: move one position at a time, by swapping order between adiacent (order-wise) elements

Comment: I just updated my question with sample data and expect result @D-Shih

Comment: I just updated my question with sample data and expect result @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: what is the action  if you update middle row order?

Comment: Thanks for your help @AhmedYousif ! I just update my question with a scenario which can help you !

Comment: No one can help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement:

```
UPDATE ...
SET [Order] = [Order] + CASE
  WHEN [Order] = @OLDPOS THEN @NEWPOS - @OLDPOS
  WHEN @NEWPOS > @OLDPOS AND [Order] > @OLDPOS AND [Order] <= @NEWPOS THEN -1
  WHEN @NEWPOS < @OLDPOS AND [Order] < @OLDPOS AND [Order] >= @NEWPOS THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

[Here are some tests](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=04dd8fd8aa6fdc6f7c17800903020a0b)

Gaps and overlaps could be fixed by adding `ROW_NUMBER()` to the above.

[Some moar tests](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9ad540df1baece3e0643838245d31d51)

Comment: But this will update all rows too ;-) Furthermore we don't know if it is just the sort order, or if the OP needs the rows numbered from 1 to n without gaps...

Comment: @Shungo just add a where clause `WHERE [Order] BETWEEN smallerof(@Old, @new) AND greaterof(@Old, @new)`. But yes, it does not solve gaps problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Yes i always need the order to go from 1 to N without gap !!

Comment: @MatthieuRigaux on second thought... it will not *fix* the gaps/overlaps if they are already there, it will simply move them around. `ROW_NUMBER()` approach would be self-correcting. I can probably convert the above to `ROW_NUMBER()` but there already is an answer.

Comment: Your solution works fine for me because i won't have gaps in my list. I will automatically add new lines at the end of the table and on DELETE i will update (if needed) the order of the other lines below to fill the gaps ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

Try this approach

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE([Name] VARCHAR(100),[Order] INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('Line 1',1) 
,('Line 2',2) 
,('Line 3',3)
,('Line 4',4);

DECLARE @OldPos INT=3, @NewPos INT=2;

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT [Name]
          ,[Order]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Order]=@OldPos 
                                           THEN CAST(@NewPos AS FLOAT) 
                                                + CASE WHEN @OldPos<@Newpos 
                                                       THEN 0.5 ELSE -0.5 END 
                                           ELSE CAST([Order] AS FLOAT) END) AS ComputedPos 
    FROM @tbl 
)
UPDATE cte SET [Order] = ComputedPos
WHERE [Order]<>ComputedPos;

SELECT * FROM @tbl ORDER BY [Order];
```

This uses an *updateable CTE*. The comment by *Damian_The_Unbeliever* gave me the idea without the need to change the order's data type.

The function `ROW_NUMBER` will do some computation in its `OVER` clause. If the `[Order]` has the right input value we will set the new position *between* the new neighbours by adding `0.5` or `-0.5` to the new position. This depends on the *direction* you are moving your row.

Comment: @SalmanA True, thx for the hint. Added `WHERE [Order]<>ComputedPos` as last line